# Opposite word of "addiction"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

Though the very obvious opposite of the word *addiction* is "deaddiction", I couldn't find the latter in any dictionary (I checked in Oxford, Chambers and Cambridge). Why is it so?

If "deaddiction" is not the real antonym, then please suggest another.

Comment: Then where did you find it?

Comment: @BarrieEngland, Heard many people saying

Comment: It's not the very obvious opposite coz it's the first time I heard this word

Comment: Then the reason you haven't found it in the standard dictionaries is that they would require documentary evidence of its existence. In any case, 'deaddiction' sounds like the process of becoming no longer addicted, rather than the opposite of addiction, for which I very much doubt if there is any word at all.

Comment: Dead diction? Is that how they speak Latin these days?

Comment: Shouldn't that be "_de-diction_", rather than "_de-addiction_"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem with asking for an antonym is that most words have more than one nuance or meaning, so antonyms can branch off into more than one direction – and sometimes even several.

In the case of *addiction*, I can think of at least two senses of the word:

There's *addiction* as a chemical, biological, or psychological dependency, usually regarded as detrimental to one's well-being (e.g., *drug addiction, sex addiction, gambling addiction*).

Then there's *addiction* used in a less scientific way, where it describes more of a rabid obsession than a true dependency (as in, *addicted to fishing, golf, or romance novels*).

The NOAD describes it like this:

[image]

So, as for antonyms: when talking about the latter usage, we might try words like:

**indifference, apathy, disinterest**

> Bob is addicted to bowling, but his wife Mary is indifferent about it.
>
> My daughter had a Pokemon addiction in grade school, but she finally grew out of it, and feels only apathy now.

But when we are talking about the former usage – such as someone's bout with alcoholism, or struggle to quit smoking – words like *disinterest* and *dispassion* don't work very well as antonyms.  I'm more inclined to suggest words like:

**independence, autonomy, freedom**

> Paul has been free from his nicotine addiction for six years now.
>
> I thought Mary had finally gained independence from her alcoholism, but it seems like she can't stay on the wagon.

Comment: Your ansewers are always perfect. +1

Answer (score 6):

You're probably referring to the term used with a hyphen: "de-addiction." You can easily find this one in the dictionary.

Without the punctuation, it's a bit tricky to read and recognize.

This is a specific term used in health and substance-withdrawal fields.

Comment: "Addiction" as a Noun has its usual antonym in the words "Aversion" and "Repellence/ Repellency."

Answer (score 2):

Various comments and answers have already stated the majority of this, but I think a complete answer needs to have it all:

Basically, a word can have many antonyms, depending on which definition - or which part of the definition - one intends to negate.

When "addiction" refers to the *process of becoming addicted to something*, the antonym would indeed be **[de-addiction](http://deaddiction.org/)** - the process of becoming no longer addicted.

"Addiction" also often refers to *an uncontrollable desire for something*. We can negate this one way by using **aversion** or **revulsion** (although those are more directly antonyms to *attraction*) - an uncontrollable desire to avoid something.

We can negate this another way by using **indifference** or something similar - the lack of any particular desire for something.

When "addiction" refers specifically to the *inability to not use a substance*, possible antonyms are **independence** or **freedom**. (I think the former is particularly good here, because drug addiction is commonly called *chemical dependence*.)

Finally, one can always use *non-* to make an ad-hoc antonym for any noun - *non-addiction* is the state of not being addicted, whatever "addicted" may mean in this context. This kind of construction might be useful in certain kinds of writing - for instance, if we wanted to describe the participants in a controlled study as either *addicts* or *non-addicts*.

Answer (score 2):

If the term *addiction* is used in the sense of the disease or state of addiction (as opposed to the *process* of becoming addicted to, or dependent upon, something), one good antonym would be *sobriety*.

> Jo got her six-month chip, recognizing a half year of *sobriety*.

Answer (score 1):

Possible answers to your question are **Divergence**, **Deviation**, **Liberation** and **Aversion**.

De-addiction is more of the process of getting off an addiction rather than the antonymous noun form of addiction.

Divergence and Deviation are synonymous in the sense that they both mean to move away from something.

Since Addiction can be thought of as a form of enslavement, Liberation seems to go well, as in *His liberation from alcohol was largely in thanks to Alcoholics Anonymous*.

Some people claim Aversion as an answer, but I do not wholly agree as it denotes dislike towards something rather, and the antonym of aversion is attraction, but I guess it can be used in a certain sense.

Answer (score 1):

how about the word "bete noire" .... it means hatred/fear/dislike

Answer (score -2):

How about *phobia* — if addiction is the overwhelming urge to go towards something, then the overwhelming urge to avoid it would be a phobia.